# How to internationalize Rails app from url when logged out and user profile when logged in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'm trying to implement internationalization on the RailsTutorial Sample App.

I managed to store a locale attribute for each user, and URL localization like `myurl.com/en` and `myurl.com/es`. The point is how to combine both methods and internationalize my app with URL params when the user is logged out, otherwise use his own preference.

I have this so far. At this point, the user preference overrides the URL param, but if a user selects `es` language and navigates to `myapp.com/en` the content is displayed in Spanish. I want the URL to not have that param if the user is logged in.

```
# application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  before_action :set_locale

  def default_url_options(options = {})
    {locale: I18n.locale}.merge options
  end

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = (current_user&.locale) || params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  end
end

# users_controller.rb
def change_locale
  user = current_user
  user.locale = params[:locale]
  user.save
  redirect_to request.referer
end

# routes.rb

post 'international/:locale' => 'users#change_locale', as: 'international'
scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|es/ do
  # All my routes
end
get '/:locale' => 'static_pages#home' # Fix the home route

# _footer.html.erb
...
<li>
  <%= link_to t('spanish'), international_path(locale: :es), :method => :post %>
</li>
<li>
  <%= link_to t('english'), international_path(locale: :en), :method => :post %>
</li>
...
```

I18n.available_locales output

```
[:en, :"da-DK", :"en-GB", :he, :"en-NZ", :"en-au-ocker", :uk, :"en-CA", :ja, :"en-BORK", :"zh-CN", :ru, :de, :"en-AU", :"de-AT", :pl, :"ca-CAT", :fr, :"fi-FI", :vi, :"en-UG", :nl, :"en-SG", :nep, :pt, :ko, :es, :sv, :ca, :"de-CH", :"zh-TW", :sk, :"en-IND", :it, :"en-US", :"pt-BR", :fa, :"nb-NO"]
```

My view code looks as this (right now there are only two links)

```
<li>
  <%= link_to "Español", international_path(locale: :es), :metho    d => :post %>
</li>
<li>
  <%= link_to "English", international_path(locale: :en), :method     => :post %>
</li>
```

PryRpl debugging:
When I'm logged in: If I write manually the URL it always go to the user stored language despite which URL I write. It always displays the user preference (`:en` or `:es`)
When i'm logged in and I click on an explicit view locale link (one of the above): The user preference is changed so it loads the new language stored to the user pref.
When I'm not logged in: It uses the URL param.

Comment: Can you put a binding.pry or similar debugger in the set_locale function and  verify what is being set?  This could be several issues and it is hard to tell from what you have posted.  Is this a pure rails application?  What does your view look like?  What is the output of I18n.available_locales?

Comment: Updated question. Can you tell me about binding.pry and why or how could I use it to provide por information about my problem? Thank you. ruby_newbie

Comment: Added info about pry debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution thanks to a coworker.

```
def set_locale
  # Change current_user&.locale to enable ruby <2.3 compatibility
  I18n.locale = (current_user.locale if current_user) || params[:locale] || I18n.default_locale
  redirect_to locale: I18n.locale if request.get? && params[:locale] != I18n.locale.to_s
end
```

If anyone knows a better solution please post an answer with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 def set_locale
   if user_signed_in?
   I18n.locale = current_user.language
 else
   I18n.locale = params[:lang] || locale_from_header || I18n.default_locale
  end
end

def locale_from_header
 request.env.fetch('HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE', '').scan(/[a-z]{2}/).first
end
```

Comment: Code-only answers may solve the OP's problem, but an explanation will help everyone understand how/why.